# Grabing ajax content after its load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

sorry my bad english. I have a function to manipulate ajax like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ajax", function(e){ 
//dynamic contents here, getting the href value from links.
});
```

Now I need manipulate the content of the ajax request AFTER IS LOADED, adding some others functions to specific elements (add ajaxForm() to form elements, and others ). The case is: how to bind these functions WITHOUT a specific event? Per example, in the "contact.php" page and I want grab the  tag to manipulate this, but the

```
$("form")
```

tag is not accessible.

If through a click, I would use

```
$(document).on("click", "element", function(e){
```

but no click event

How I can get this? Thks

---

**Aditional information:**

I want this:

```
ajaxLoader(content, "#mainDiv"); //loading a content. ajaxLoader is a .ajax() function
form1 = $("#mainDiv").find('#formOne'); //I need grad form like this
var options = { 
            beforeSend: function() 
            {   
                $("#progress").show(); //inacessible
                $("#bar").width('0%'); //inacessible
                $("#message").html(""); //inacessible
                $("#percent").html("0%"); //inacessible

            },
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
            {
               //foo
            },
            success: function() 
            {
                //bar
            },
            complete: function(response) 
            {   
               //foo
            }
    }; 
$(form1).ajaxForm(options);   //inacessible
```

Comment: what about document.ready()?

Comment: are you loading the content into a specific container?

Comment: Thanks Eisa Adil but as far as I know this method works only in the main DOM of the page, and not on the content loaded dynamically...

Comment: Yes PlantTheIdea, everything is loaded into a main container.... (#main)

Comment: Even if you did `$(document).on("click", "form", function(e) { alert( 'Hi'); } `? You won't be able to simply collect an Ajax loaded `$('form')`, it would have to be *looked* for first, e.g. `$(document).find('form')` or `$('#container).find('form')`

Comment: Thanks MackieeE, your answer is close to what I need to know. However, I tried something like:
ajaxLoader(content, "#mainDiv"); $("#mainDiv")find('form') but this does not work.. Is that so?

Answer (score -1):

Use the `.success` callback on your AJAX call. That's is why it is there.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, but this does not solve because I do not have an ajax call for each content, but a single call for dozens of different dynamic pages, so I would be unfeasible to add .success for each of them ....

Comment: No, you'd write a single function to handle it all and pass the context of the content element to the function so you don't end up repeating blocks of code.